# ASP.NET DataList - Column Width and Indent Panel

Tags: asp.net, css

This code below is working fine, but the columns are so close together. Is there a way to set the width for each column? Also, is there a way to indent the whole "pnlChildView"?

Thanks,

```
<asp:DataList BackColor="#ffffff" id="DataList1" DataSourceID="dsCompanyList"  
              runat="server" Width="100%" DataKeyField="Company"
              UseAccessibleHeader="true" CssClass="books"
              HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" ItemStyle-CssClass="item"
              AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="alternating"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="+" 
                        CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>'
                        OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command"  
                        Font-Underline="false">
        </asp:LinkButton>
        <%#Eval("Row")%>
        <%#Eval("Company")%>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server" style="margin-right:50px;">
            <asp:DataList ID="childList" runat="server" Width="100%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%#Eval("FirstName")%></td>
                        <td><%#Eval("LastName")%></td>                        
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying style to the TDs e.g. :

```
<td style="width: 200px;"><%#Eval("FirstName")%></td>
<td style="width: 300px;"><%#Eval("LastName")%></td>
```

Adjust it with padding and other properties as needed.

For your main panel instead of `style="margin-right:50px;` try `style="padding-left:50px;` to indent it.

Comment: I tried as your suggestion, and it seems work. But somehow, when I try style="width:30%;", using percentage for the width, it didn't work.. any idea why?

Comment: @milacay percentage width maybe very tricky, it's supposed to be percent of something, meaning container has to have fixed width (for example table parent of TR/TDs). I would advice against using percentage. If your only problem that the columns stick too close together, instead of "width", use "padding-left", "padding-right" styles.

Comment: Thank you for helping. One quick question. Is the a way to show the border line each column? I tried this "<td style="width: 200px; border:solid 1px black;">", but it looks really nasty, each repeated row has a little box inside with value. It doesn't look like regular HTML table/row.  please advise.

Comment: Add to the main table style (or in your case DataList, I guess) `style="border-collapse:collapse"`

Comment: no luck. Maybe DataList is a wrong type to use for display rows. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate space between your columns using the `CellPadding` attribute of the `DataList`, like this:

```
<asp:DataList CellPadding="10"
```

Note: The unit for cell padding is pixels.

Use either CSS `margin` or `padding` for you indentation, like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server" style="margin:50px;">
```

Note: `margin` by itself will apply the same margin value to all four sides of the box. Use `margin-left`, `margin-top`, `margin-right` or `margin-bottom` for individual sides of the box.

OR

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server" style="padding:50px;">
```

Note: `padding` by itself will apply the same padding value to all four sides of the box. Use `padding-left`, `padding-top`, `padding-right` or `padding-bottom` for individual sides of the box.

Read [What’s the Difference Between Margins and Padding?](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-between-margins-padding-css/) for more information.